# Como establecer margen en BorderLayout?

Tags: java, layout

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> El frame tiene BorderLayout y contiene dos paneles, center y west (4 botones de la derecha).
>          Pregunta 1:
>             El panel de la derecha está organizado con un GridLayout. Y lo que me gustaría es establecer un margen.
>          Pregunta 2: La parte de la izda está contenida en el panel center y dentro de center hay 3 paneles. El de arriba contiene sólo la etiqueta "Impresora: Mi impresora" y lo que me gustaría es justificarla a la izda dejando algo de margen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pregunta 1: El panel de la derecha está organizado con un GridLayout.
>   Y lo que me gustaría es establecer un margen.

Para ese propósito puede serte de mucha utilidad establecer un tipo de borde al contenedor `west`. `EmptyBorder` ofrece la posibilidad de ajustar el ancho del borde (*que no tiene color*) y se obtendría ese espaciado que se busca:

`west.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,0,5,5));`

En él los cuatro valores enteros tienen un orden especifico: el primer `0` representa el grosor del borde superior del `JPanel`, el segundo `0` representa el grosor del borde izquierdo, el primer `5` al borde inferior y el ultimo al borde derecho.

> Pregunta 2: La parte de la izda está contenida en el panel center y
>   dentro de center hay 3 paneles. El de arriba contiene sólo la etiqueta
>   "Impresora: Mi impresora" y lo que me gustaría es justificarla a la
>   izda dejando algo de margen

Si el panel `center` usa el `FlowLayout` *default* ten en cuenta que éste distribuye los componentes de manera centrada en el contenedor (*constante* `FlowLayout.CENTER`), una aproximación puede ser especificando tal alineación:

`center.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));// o LEFT`

Ahora cada componente agregado estará ubicado partiendo desde la izquierda del contendor `center`.

Comment: Mil gracias. Edité la primera pregunta en el programa y fenómeno. La segunda tengo que darle más vueltas, pues el panel center tiene 3 JTextArea y dos paneles de botones con Grid. ordenados los 5 componentes  con un Flow. Abajo un panel con 3 componentes en Flow tb. En principio arriba creé sólo una etiqueta pero más tarde pensé que quizá podía ser mejor poner la etiqueta sobre un panel y mover la etiqueta sobre ese panel y no sobre el frame dónde están otros paneles. Pero no se si se puede mover esa etiqueta por su panel